# SWFobject embedded swf, ExternalInterface.Call returns null

Tags: django, flash

im working on a flash game with django backend using swfobject to embed the swf into the view, 
however when i do externalinterface.call() from flash in InternetExplorer(Chrome and Firefox are fine), it returns null

the flash game itself works perfectly

Django view and embed code:

```
<div id="game_container">
    <div id='flashContent'></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
    var flashvars={{flashvars|safe}};
    var params={wmode:"opaque", allowscriptaccess:"always" };
    var attributes={id:"flashContent", name:"flashContent"};
    swfobject.embedSWF("{{SWF_URL}}", "flashContent", "{{ appsettings.SWF_WIDTH }}", "{{ appsettings.SWF_HEIGHT }}", "10.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>


function fqlearn_isEventInteresting(data) {
ln_log(['isEventInteresting',data]);
if (!BASE_URL) BASE_URL = data.baseURL;
ln_log(['got lesson?',fqlearn_findLearningModule(data) != null]);
return fqlearn_findLearningModule(data) != null;
//shuld return either true or false.
}
```

Flash AS3 code:

```
var isInteresting:Object = false;

        try {
            isInteresting = ExternalInterface.call('fqlearn_isEventInteresting', data);
        } catch (e:Error) {
            trace("error calling external interface");
            // Container does not support outgoing calls :/
            rpc.forceLogUncaughtError("ExternalInterface.call problem",
                e.name, e.toString(), e.getStackTrace());
            rest.apply(restThis);
            return;
        } catch (e:SecurityError) {
            // Security sandbox nonsense :/
            throw e;
        }

        if (isInteresting == null) {
            // Something went wrong :/
            rpc.forceLogUncaughtError("ExternalInterface.call problem", "JS_returned_null_error");
        }

        if (isInteresting) {
            trace("showing learning blackout")
            dispatch(CoordinationEvent.newLEARNING_ABOUT_TO_SHOW());

            learningPendingData = {
                rest: rest,
                restThis: restThis
            };
```

ExternalInterface.call() from Flash in InternetExplorer(Chrome and Firefox are fine), it returns null . how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it: `console.debug` was choking up Internet Explorer. I removed those and it worked.